# How to get contents or index of the PDF

Tags: ios, pdf, tableofcontents

How to get contents or index of the PDF in iOS programmatically. Means the chapter contents.

Comment: Be more specific (do it quickly because this question is likely to get put on hold within 30 minutes).

Comment: can we get the content or index details from the pdf like chapter 1 and page no. and sub points of whole pdf.

Answer (score 1):

try PSPDFKit for all about the pdf solution..

[PSPDFKit](https://github.com/PSPDFKit/PSPDFKit-Demo)

and other information on http://pspdfkit.com/ and [Documents](http://pspdfkit.com/documentation.html)

it may help you..