# iOS: Internal content search in PDF document

Tags: ios, search, pdf

We are developing document based iOS application and we need a search function which not only searches on the title of the pdf's but also in the content of the pdf.

Is this possible with objective-c/ios?

Thanks,
Mahesh M.

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419262/how-to-get-contents-or-index-of-the-pdf/17419442#17419442

Comment: and in this frame work http://pspdfkit.com/api/Classes/PSPDFSearchHighlightView.html is useful

Comment: Have a look a complete example https://github.com/Jageen/PDFSearch